# how to use page break dompdf in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

i use page-break-before: always in pdf success but when move the next page the table is not neat.
what should I do next?
'Thanks'

this is my code:

.page-break{ page-break-before: always; }

```
                <?php $e= 0 ?>
                @foreach($dt as $data)
                    <?php $e++ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$e}}</td>
                        <td>{{$data->part_number}}</td>
                        <td>{{$data->part_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$data->model_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$data->category}}</td>
                        <td>{{$data->request_qty}}</td>
                    </tr>
                        @if($e %  30  == 0)
                            <div class="page-break" ></div>
                        @endif
                @endforeach
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you probably don't want a div in an open table that isn't placed in a row and cell ... side note that css property won't apply to empty divs that won't generate a box

Answer (score 0):

I tried in several ways, the only way i can make it work, was calculating a height. When you do a page break, must be in the end of table. Not is the best way, but works for me.

```
<table >            
        <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>                                               
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
                @php($pixel=0)              
                @foreach($datos as $item)                       
                    @if($pixel >= 250)
                        @php($pixel = 0)                            
                        <table ><tbody>
                    @endif
                    <tr>                            
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    @php($pixel +=10)
                    @if($pixel >= 250)                          
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <div class="page-break"></div>
                    @endif
                @endforeach                 
            </tbody>                
        </table>
```